# How indexing $and operator over $or operator

Tags: mongodb

Good morning. I have some problems. I have these fields:

```
name: "Mike",
city: "NY",
address: "something",
pets: ["dog", "cat"]
```

I created indexes

```
db.person.ensureIndex({name: 1})
db.person.ensureIndex({city: 1})
db.person.ensureIndex({address: 1})
db.person.ensureIndex({pets: 1})
```

And query is

```
db.person.find({$and: [{$or: [{name: "Mike"}, {city: "CA"}]}, {pets: "dog"}]}).explain()
```

And i didn't get B_tree query.. I got BasicCursor... How do it fix?

Comment: by taking out the redundant $and

Comment: I think in this case you should use compound indexes.

Comment: yes. Of couse. I use compound indexes too. Дмитрий, я также использую все возможные индексы. Но когда я оборачиваю and вокруг or - индексы отваливаются

Comment: first, which index do you expect this query should use?  second you need to remove the unneeded $and.  $or has two clauses each can use a separate index.  Best combination (for this query) is compound index on name and city and simple index on pets.

Answer (score 1):

May be time to upgrade your MongoDB version. Using v2.2.1 I get a BTree cursor.

```
> db.person.insert({name: "Mike", city: "NY", address: "something", pets: ["dog", "cat"]})
> db.person.ensureIndex({name: 1})
> db.person.ensureIndex({city: 1})
> db.person.ensureIndex({address: 1})
> db.person.ensureIndex({pets: 1})
> db.person.find({$and: [{$or: [{name: "Mike"}, {city: "CA"}]}, {pets: "dog"}]}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor pets_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "pets" : [
                        [
                                "dog",
                                "dog"
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: may be. But my version is 2.2.3 :)  Hm.. It's work for me too. But more harder not working. I'll try find bug

Comment: For example {$and: [{$or: [{name: 'Mike'}, {city: 'CA'}]}, {$or: [{pets: {$all: 'dog'}}, {address: 'smtg'}]}]}

Comment: @KirillMuchow That query won't show btree cursor in the explain, it will only the btree explain for results of one $or, if you put in two $ors then it will show normal cursor but that does not mean it isn't using a index for those $ors